# How to resolve parseError REST response from Google Calendar API

Tags: rest, delphi, google-calendar-api

I am trying to send a POST request to the Google Calendar API using the Delphi REST controls.
This is the data I am trying to send a jsonObject:

```
jsonObjEventResource := '{"summary":"test","description":"testing","id":"06824945162f4204bfdc041ae1bbae85","start":{"date":"2018-04-18"},"end":{"date":"2018-04-18"},"guestsCanInviteOthers":false,"visibility":"private"}';

RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
RESTRequest.Body.ClearBody;
RESTRequest.Body.Add(jsonObjEventResource,ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
RESTRequest.Execute;
```

I do have access to the GET methods but I am unable to POST.
This is my URI: `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?access_token={access_token}`.
My scope is : `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`;
Is there any way to resolve the parseError reponse from Google? I saw other people have the same error with the client libraries but those work arounds don't work for me.

**EDIT:**
Answer:

```
var
  atemp : TStringList;
  memStream : TMemoryStream;
begin
  atemp:=TStringList.Create;
  memStream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    atemp.Add(EventResource.ToJSON);
    atemp.SaveToStream(memStream);

    aRESTRequest.Method:= rmPOST;
    aRESTRequest.Resource:= 'calendars/primary/events'+'?access_token='+AccessToken;
    aRESTRequest.Params.AddItem('access_token', AccessToken,pkGETorPOST);
    aRESTRequest.AddBody(memStream, ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
  finally
    atemp.Free;
    memStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Question editted to include better and more complete code

Comment: Your end -> date is not correct, should be 1 day more:
"date": "2018-04-19"
Documentation of the Calendar API:
The (exclusive) end time of the event. For a recurring event, this is the end time of the first instance.

Comment: @Fritzw unfortunately that is not the case. i changed it and it still gave the error. i used the Try Me on https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert and it accepted the same date for both start and end. I copied that json string and it still gives the error.

Comment: This is a son I can send without problems:   
{
 "colorId": "1",
 "description": "Test",
 "id": "82f3k3obm9ke5n4lp4p7sg3ij24c025nbmbsmtm1tjk2tr8jk9oosr9eg2cgr7ci03hm40hbmtub8",
 "location": "",
 "summary": "Test",
 "start": {
  "date": "2018-04-20"
 },
 "end": {
  "date": "2018-04-21"
 }
}

Is your OAuth2 setup correct?

Comment: yes my OAuth is set up correctly.i can get my access and refresh tokens. My scope is for managing calendars so that isn't the problem either and your json does not work either in my test app

Answer (score 0):

add a comma on line 12

```
'end': {
    'dateTime': '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
  },
```

and in

```
'reminders': {
    'useDefault': false,
    'overrides': [
      {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
      {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10}
    ]
  }
```

for minutes calculate the value and pass that variable, do not just send 24 * 60

Comment: I updated the code with my actual json string. I get the same error with both of them